# Angular RouterTestingModule and params on activatedRoute

Tags: angular

I've just created an angular 13 project with angular cli (ng new command).

I've the following AppComponent

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'angular-router-testing';

  queryParam: string = 'gaetano';
  routingParam: string = 'ciro';

  constructor(private readonly activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.routingParam = params['routingParam'];
    });

    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe( queryParams => {
      this.queryParam = queryParams['queryParam'];
    });
  }
}
```

and the following test

```
import {ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let target: AppComponent;

  let router: Router;
  let location: Location;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([{
          path: 'prova/:routingParam',
          component: AppComponent
        }])
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    target = fixture.componentInstance;

    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    location = TestBed.inject(Location);
  });

  it('should manage routing', async () => {
    const navigationResult = await router.navigate(['prova', '1000'], {queryParams: {queryParam: '2000'}});
    expect(navigationResult).toBeTrue();

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(target.queryParam).toEqual('2000');
    expect(location.path()).toEqual('/prova/1000?queryParam=2000');
    expect(target.routingParam).toEqual('1000');
  });
});
```

I'm able to pass correctly the queryParam, but I'm not able to pass the param.
Why the last expectation is failing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may help you.

```
it('should check activate route', fakeAsync(() => {
        let route = TestBed.inject(ActivatedRoute);
        route.url = of([
          { path: 'pathurl', parameters: {}, parameterMap: {} as ParamMap },
        ]);
     // method
     // expectations
      }));
```